# Get top row from duplicate rows without a unique column

Tags: mysql

I have a table called a which has columns b,c and d..It looks like below

```
b   c   d
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
```

There are no unique columns.I want to query either first row or the last row.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: i am getting duplicate entry error when i query since there are multiple records.I want to fetch column b from any one the rows

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table - at least not in the sense of a relational database

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `LIMIT` query without an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT b, c, d
FROM yourTable
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that there is no "first" or "last" row unless you also tell us what the logic for ordering is.  A more typical query would be:

```
SELECT b, c, d
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY <some_col>
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i am actually trying to create a view with this select query.and it is failing with returns more than one row error.